# Error: Variable "BOOL" is not a type name

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I am trying to create a very simple MFC application when suddenly Visual Studio decides it no longer recognizes what a `BOOL` is.

I cannot figure out why this is happening. Does anyone know why this is going on and how to fix it?

[image: Error]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a closing semi-colon at the end of your class.

```
class CApp : public CWinApp {
    ...
}; <---
```

This is the proper class syntax. I'm sure you know that and just happened to delete it and missed the simple error. I would say when you look at the error report it's best to solve the topmost one first. Doing so can eliminate other errors in the list especially in the case of a `;`. Your image reflects that on the first line where it tells you about a missing `;`.

Comment: Thanks I can't believe I missed that :(

Comment: Just like to add, this will continue to happen through-out your entire programming life...just laugh at it.